# Я не могу создать выход из сервера по событию/ивенту в discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот

Мой текущий код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('$leave'):
    await message.channel.send('Уже выхожу.')
    await discord.Guild.leave()
```

Но `await discord.Guild.leave()` не работает. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызывать метод `leave()` у какого-то конкретного сервера, а не у стандартного объекта `discord.Guild`

Объект сервера можно получить из объекта сообщения (`message`), который вы получаете в качестве аргумента функции `on_message()`. Точно также во второй строке функции вы получаете из сообщения объект канала (`channel`)

Должно быть как-то так:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('$leave'):
    await message.channel.send('Уже выхожу.')
    await message.guild.leave()
```